# Polly policy to log exception and rethrow

Tags: c#, exception, polly

I consider to use  [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#handing-return-values-and-policytresult)  to create policy to log exception and rethrow.
I didn't find an existing method that allow it out of the box , but some options that I see are

**Fallback**

```
// Specify a substitute value or func, calling an action (e.g. for logging)
// if the fallback is invoked.
Policy.Handle<Whatever>()
.Fallback<UserAvatar>(UserAvatar.Blank,
    onFallback: (exception, context) =>
    {
        _logger.Log(exception, context);
        throw exception;
    });
```

Question: is it ok to throw exception from Fallback?

**Timeout**

```
Policy.Timeout(1, T30meoutStrategy.Pessimistic,
(context, timespan, task) =>
{
    // ContinueWith important!: the abandoned task may very well still be executing,
    // when the caller times out on waiting for it!
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            logger.Error(context,t.Exception);
            throw exception;
        }
    });
}
```

Or **Retry**

```
Policy.Handle<DivideByZeroException>().Retry(0,
(exception, retryCount) =>
{
    logger.Error(context,exception);
    throw exception;
});
```

Question: is 0 retries supported?

Or KISS and write **simple try/catch** with throw by myself.

Which of these methods is better?
What are your recommendation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do not already have Polly in the mix, try/catch would seem simplest.

If you already have Polly in the mix, [`FallbackPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) can safely be re-purposed in the way you suggest.  The `onFallback` delegate and fallback action or value [are not governed by the `.Handle<>()` clauses of the Policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/089e7b51bf9970668bb1ca87ad9ea6ed401dbaed/src/Polly.Shared/Fallback/FallbackEngine.cs#L44-L46), so you can safely rethrow an exception from within the `onFallback` delegate.

```
Policy<UserAvatar>.Handle<Whatever>()
.Fallback<UserAvatar>(UserAvatar.Blank,
    onFallback: (exception, context) =>
    {
        _logger.Log(exception, context);
        throw exception;
    });
```

---

The approach your question outlines with [`TimeoutPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) would only capture exceptions thrown by delegates the caller had earlier walked away from due to timeout, and only in `TimeoutMode.Pessimistic`; not all exceptions.

---

The approach your question outlines with `.Retry(0, ...)` would not work.  If no retries are specified, the `onRetry` delegate would not be invoked.

---

To avoid the untidiness of repurposing `FallbackPolicy`, you could also code your own `LogThenRethrowPolicy`, within Polly's structures.  [This commit](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/commit/98bc9317e2c050702f91b2df31c3b653c458f3a7) (which added the simple [`NoOpPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/NoOp)) exemplifies the minimum necessary to add a new policy.  You could add an implementation similar to `NoOpPolicy` but just `try { } catch { /* log; rethrow */ }`

---

**EDIT January 2019**: Polly.Contrib now also contains a [Polly.Contrib.LoggingPolicy](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.LoggingPolicy) which can help with this.

Comment: Do you know where the NuGet package is for the LoggingPolicy? I don't see a link on the GitHub, and I tried searching NuGet for Polly.Contrib and Polly.Contrib.LoggingPolicy. Neither package seems to exist, although I found some sub-packages for Polly.Contrib that didn't seem related.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples/blob/master/PollyDemos/Async/AsyncDemo02_WaitAndRetryNTimes.cs shows that you can use the `onRetry:` option, at least for WaitAndRetryAsync. I haven't looked at the others yet.

```
HttpPolicyExtensions
.HandleTransientHttpError()
.WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))  // exponential back-off: 2, 4, 8 etc
                    + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Jitterer.Next(0, 1000)), // plus some jitter: up to 1 second
    onRetry: (response, calculatedWaitDuration) =>
    {
        logger.LogError($"Failed attempt. Waited for {calculatedWaitDuration}. Retrying. {response.Exception.Message} - {response.Exception.StackTrace}");
    }
);
```

Comment: I didn’t want to retry, just log and re-throw.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution with generic method

```
public async Task<T> PollyRetry<T>(
        Func<Task<T>> action)
    {

        bool hasFallback = false;
        Exception ex = null;

        var fallbackPolicy = Policy<T>.Handle<Exception>().FallbackAsync(
            default(T), d =>
            {
                //log final exception

                ex = d.Exception;

                hasFallback = true;
                return Task.FromResult(new { });

            });

        var retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
                retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                (res, timeSpan, context) =>
                {
                    //log exception
                });

        var policyResult = await fallbackPolicy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy).ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(action);

        if (hasFallback && ex != null)
            throw ex;

        return policyResult.Result;
    }
```

---

```
//call service with retry logic
        TestResponse response = await _pollyRetryService.PollyRetry(async () =>
        {
            return await _testService.Test(input);

        });
```

Comment: I would suggest to use [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913559/c-rethrow-an-exception-from-a-variable-while-preserving-stack-trace/64913808#64913808) instead of re-throwing the exception.