# How to make fallback for circuit breaker invoked on all retries on the broken circuit

Tags: c#, asp.net, polly, bulkhead

I have the following policies:

```
var sharedBulkhead = Policy
        .BulkheadAsync(
            maxParallelization: maxParallelizations, 
            maxQueuingActions: maxQueuingActions,
            onBulkheadRejectedAsync: (context) =>
            {
                Log.Info($"Bulk head rejected => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
            }
        );

var retryPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            retryCount: maxRetryCount,
            sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt)),
            onRetryAsync: (exception, calculatedWaitDuration, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                Log.Error($"Retry => Count: {retryCount}, Wait duration: {calculatedWaitDuration}, Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}, Exception: {exception}.");
                return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
            });

            var circuitBreaker = Policy.Handle<Exception>(e => (e is HttpRequestException)).CircuitBreakerAsync(
            exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: maxExceptionsBeforeBreaking, 
            durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(circuitBreakDurationSeconds), 
            onBreak: (exception, timespan, context) =>
            {
                Log.Error($"Circuit broken => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}, Exception: {exception}");
            },
            onReset: (context) =>
            {
                Log.Info($"Circuit reset => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
            }
        );

var fallbackForCircuitBreaker = Policy<bool>
         .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
         .FallbackAsync(
             fallbackValue: false,
             onFallbackAsync: (b, context) =>
             {
                 Log.Error($"Operation attempted on broken circuit => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                 return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
             }
         );

var fallbackForAnyException = Policy<bool>
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .FallbackAsync(
                fallbackAction: (ct, context) => { return Task.FromResult(false); },
                onFallbackAsync: (e, context) =>
                {
                    Log.Error($"An unexpected error occured => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                    return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
                }
            );


var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead);
var policyWrap = fallbackForAnyException.WrapAsync(fallbackForCircuitBreaker.WrapAsync(resilienceStrategy));
```

Now, `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` is only invoked if all retries fail, and if the last retry fails with `BrokenCircuitException`. What changes should be made in order for `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` to be invoked every time a retry is made on a broken circuit?

Also, I am using a `sharedBulkHead` which is an instance field in the service and is initialized in the constructor. Is that a good practise? What is to be done ideally on `onBulkheadRejectedAsync`? Can I modify the retry policy to handle bulk head rejection as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, fallbackForCircuitBreaker is only invoked if all retries fail, and if the last retry fails with BrokenCircuitException. What changes should be made in order for fallbackForCircuitBreaker to be invoked every time a retry is made on a broken circuit?

See the [PolicyWrap documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap), especially the [diagrams and description of operation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#operation). Policies in a PolicyWrap act like a sequence of nested middleware around the call:

- the outermost (leftmost in reading order) policy executes the next inner, which executes the next inner, etc; until the innermost policy executes the user delegate;
- a thrown exception bubbles back outwards (until handled) through the layers

So, to make (an equivalent to) `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` invoked per try, move it inside the retry policy.

The current `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` however substitutes the thrown exception with a return value `false`, whereas it sounds like what you are seeking from fallback-per-try is a 'log, then make the next try'.  The technique for that is to use fallback as [log then rethrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43016211/), so that your retry policy can still respond to the (rethrown) exception.  So:

```
var sharedBulkhead = /* as before */;
var retryPolicy = /* as before */;
var fallbackForCircuitBreaker = /* as before */;
var logCircuitBreakerBrokenPerTry = Policy<bool>
     .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
     .FallbackAsync(
         fallbackValue: false,
         onFallbackAsync: (outcome, context) =>
         {
             Log.Error($"Operation attempted on broken circuit => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
             throw outcome.Exception;
         }
     );
var fallbackForAnyException = /* as before */;

var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, logCircuitBreakerBrokenPerTry, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead);
var policyWrap = fallbackForAnyException.WrapAsync(fallbackForCircuitBreaker.WrapAsync(resilienceStrategy));
```

---

> Can I modify the retry policy to handle bulk head rejection as well?

The [Polly bulkhead documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead#syntax) states the policy throws `BulkheadRejectedException`, so:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
    .Or<BulkheadRejectedException>()
    /* etc */
```

> What is to be done ideally on onBulkheadRejectedAsync?

You can log. Broadly speaking, you can shed the excess load, or use the bulkhead rejection as a trigger to scale horizontally to increase capacity.  The Polly documentation provides more discussion [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Transient-fault-handling-and-proactive-resilience-engineering#bulkhead) and [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead#configuration-recommendations).

> Also, I am using a sharedBulkHead which is an instance field in the service and is initialized in the constructor. Is that a good practise?

It depends. The lifetime of the Bulkhead policy instance must be [long-lived across the governed calls](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead#scoping-bulkhead-instances), not per call, in order for the state of the Bulkhead policy instance to govern the number of calls executing concurrently.

- If the service exists as a long-lived singleton, holding the bulkhead policy in an instance field would be appropriate as the bulkhead policy instance would also be long lived.
- If instances of the service class are created as transient/per-request by a DI container, you would need to ensure the bulkhead policy instance was still long-lived and shared across concurrent requests (eg by making it `static`), not per-request.
- If instances of the bulkhead are configured on an HttpClient by HttpClientFactory, follow the notes on [scoping stateful policies with HttpClientFactory in the Polly and HttpClientFactory documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#with-stateful-policies-use-as-selector-not-factory).