# C#: Rethrow an exception from a variable while preserving stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In my codebase I have some retry functionality that stores an exception in a variable and at the end throws the exception in the variable. Imagine something like this

```
Exception exc = null;

while(condition){
   try {
      // stuff
   } catch (Exception e){
     exc = e;
   }
}

if (e != null){
   throw e;
}
```

Now, since this is a `throw e` statement and not a `throw` statement, the original stack trace is lost. Is there some way to do a rethrow that preserves the original stack trace, or will I need to restructure my code so I can use a `throw` statement?

Comment: [InnerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception)?

Comment: But then I lose my Type info, so exception handlers that look at the type will not see the original type.

Comment: Wouldn't the original exception `e` contain the stack trace in its `StackTrace` property?

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383/how-to-rethrow-innerexception-without-losing-stack-trace-in-c) might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's where [ExceptionDispatchInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo) comes into play.
It resides inside the `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices` namespace.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo edi = null;

        try
        {
            // stuff
            throw new Exception("A");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        }

        edi?.Throw();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: A
   at EDI_Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\Program.cs:line 16
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at EDI_Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\Program.cs:line 24
```

- Line 16 is where `throw new Exception("A");` is called
- Line 24 is where `edi?.Throw();` is called